# How rendering of price.phtml in catalog product listing page is happening?

Tags: magento-1.7, price, template

Catalog Product listing page's template file is `list.phtml`. Where the rendering of all the products in category happens using `foreach` loop.

I am confused about the rendering of the `price.phtml`. Because there is no block for it in handle `<catalog_category_default>`

Now, `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` returns price of the product.

How this method is linked to `price.phtml` ?

Comment: search "price.phtml" in catalog.xml in base/default/your_theme, it will be the child block to the block containing list.phtml.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Product price display

The method `getPriceHtml()` is defined in the block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`.

The method uses a price renderer which depends on the product type:

```
$type_id = $product->getTypeId(); // e.g. simple, configurable, bundle, grouped, ...
$this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
```

The price renderer is a block with an associated template. Both depend on the product type.

If there is no block or template defined for the specified product type, it defaults to the `catalog/product_price` block and the `catalog/product/price.phtml` template.

### Where are the price renderers and templates for product types defined?

The price blocks and renderers usually are specified using layout XML, so modules which add new product types can easily add their own renderers, too. For example. the bundled product adds it's price renderer as follows in the `bundle.xml` layout file:

```
<default>
    <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

### Custom price templates or renderers

Using the same mechanism it's also possible to override the default renderers. If you want to just change the template, and keep the default price block type, simply call `addPriceBlockType` in the layout file with the default block (see above) and your template.

### Rendering the price block

The code to actually render the price block looks like this:

```
$this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
    ->setProduct($product)
    ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
    ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
    ->toHtml();
```

The `$displayMinimalPrice` and `$idSuffix` variables are optional arguments to the `getPriceHtml` method.

```
public function getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice = false, $idSuffix = '')
```

The `$idSuffix` is used in the price template to complete the CSS id of the `<span>` tag surrounding the actual price, for example:

```
<span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
```

Comment: @Vinai could you please suggest something on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949796/can-we-add-more-than-one-special-price-in-magento-using-price-type-attribute

Comment: If I wanted to get the super attribute pricing would I just use <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?> or do I need to specify what type of pricing? Tiered?

Comment: Corrent. The method will determine the product type and render the price accordingly.

Comment: hi @Vinai I tried doing that, but the price stays fixed. It doesn't change when I select a color that is a different price. The top price does change, but not the one down below near add to cart. See here http://www.jennyyootest.com/index.php/adelle.html

Comment: You have to adjust the JavaScript to change both prices.