# what is the block name for price block?

Tags: layout, blocks, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

I want disable cache for price block. I was trying for last 2 days but I can't achieve it yet. I almost read all blogs and articles regarding this. And I realize that there is no block for price thing at all. I just looked up in my layout files and there is no block for this except only one thing,

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```

But when I remove this nothing was happening. Is there any specific block for it ? Or I missed something ?

And I tried template path hints to view the block name. It shows the class name of that block like `Mage_Catalog_Product_Price`

Please help me guys.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this. If yes, feel free to answer your own question

Comment: Use below code . It maybe work for you 
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" > <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>1</lifetime></action> </block>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```

use
this ...........

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" >
         <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
        </block>
```

I would recommend reviewing your theme/template in more detail. To help facilitate this https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints is great at identifying blocks that are being cached or not.

References;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3134/69

[Cache problem - prevent my module block to be cached](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19818/cache-problem-prevent-my-module-block-to-be-cached?rq=1#comment33892_19820)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Deepak, I have already tried this. Please refer this question. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49585/magento-disable-cache-for-price-block/

Comment: @Elavarasan  use this answer   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/how-rendering-of-price-phtml-in-catalog-product-listing-page-is-happening